# How can I use hyphenation in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-hyphens

I use the following css to auto hyphen text in my website:

```
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

But in chrome this has no effect. I already read, that chrome doesn't support this. Is there any workaround for hyphenation in chrome?
Thanks!

Comment: no pure css solution. but if use javascripit , it can be done, check out this javascript library [link](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator)

Comment: Star this chromium issue and comment on it:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47083

Comment: The chrome-team is working on this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605840

Comment: Works in Mac/Android Chrome since Nov 2016, but not on Windows.

Comment: In Chrome (62.0) you can currently use `hyphens: initial` to undo a previous `hyphens: none` (and allow hyphenation at `&shy;`) though the property doesn't appear to support setting any specific value other than `none`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hyphenation is currently supported on Chrome only on Android and macOS (and only the "auto" value), as you can see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

I used [Hyphenator](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator) too, as suggested by Eric.

Comment: There's no hypenathor in that production website.

Comment: @reallynice that's true, the site has changed in the meanwhile. You can see it in these archive.org snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20150419034614/http://www.chiantibanca.it/privacy-policy-S6A158E170.htm

Comment: The hyphenation does not work in Chrome on MacOs. I'm not sure about Google's Official position, but even the online CS "Try It Now" sites don't work.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else made the mistake I did, hyphens only work if you declare the language in the HTML tag. For example:
`<html lang="en-GB">`

Without a language declared `hyphens:auto` will do nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Soft hyphens can be applied with JavaScript (best solution) or any server-side language, however, that answers the question with its own answer.

Comment: That's true - unfortunately the only way for chrome right now. But beware: Doing this can affect accessibility: Screen readers will read every syllable, not whole words